# Understanding Delegates

Tags: c#

It's not the first time I come across delegates and I am as confused as I were the last time and the time before that. So once and for all I want to get the delgate-confusion cleared up.

*My problem is as followed*

Having a Graphical User Interface which only displays a ListView with some boud items, I want to load the data from a Data Connection which takes some time, to increase the comfort of using the application I have instancieted a BackgroundWorker and in the doWork-method I want to fetch the data and display it.

This is how I want it

- Create BackgroundWorker and appoint doWork_fetchData() method to the doWork event
- Call the Async method of my Worker instance
- Have the ListView updated without the User Interface beeing "frozen" during download of data.

Now this is Cross-Thread-Invoking and I wanted to solve this with Delegates which brings me here. Following [this tutorial](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html), I got a working Delegate, **However** it did not solve the problem, inside my delegate I cannot change my ListView, it still says it is on another thread.

I want to find an Easy explenation on delegates and how to use them to solve my problem. Also, should I think or design my software different?

Comment: In this case, WPF. But the answer can be more general to help a wider audience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally `BackgroundWorker` communicates with the UI thread using [`ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx). You would hook up a delegate to receive those progress events before launching the background worker, and then the progress would be reported on the UI thread, where you're safe to change your `ListView`.

The other alternative in Windows Forms is to call [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) or [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx), passing in a delegate which will update the UI. That delegate will be executed on the UI thread. For an example of this, see [my threading tutorial](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml) or [Joe Albahari's](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Apartments_and_Windows).

The equivalent of this in WPF is the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) - again, [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) and [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx). You can access the dispatcher for a control with the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks Jon, once again you are a life saver! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a ui control from a different thread directly, you need to check the `Control.InvokeRequired` property before you make a change.

See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx) on msdn

Comment: What about BindingSources, are those possible to change? Could you create a binding source which would enable you to add / remove items from a ListView?

Comment: For WPF, you would use Dispatcher.CheckAccess and Dispatcher.Invoke, rather than Control.InvokeRequired and Control.Invoke

Comment: @Filip, honestly, I'm not sure. My experience is only with Winforms in this regard, I'm fairly certain you could pass in a datasource in substitution for the string in the msdn example. Untried though!

Comment: Why do you want to use CheckAccess or InvokeRequired?

Comment: @Filip, checking InvokeRequired determines whether or not the method is being called from a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this code, it does what you need:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnFill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private delegate void AddItemToListViewDelegate(ListView view, ListViewItem item);

    private void AddItemToListView(ListView view, ListViewItem item)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new AddItemToListViewDelegate(AddItemToListView), new object[] { view, item });
            return;
        }

        view.Items.Add(item);
    }

    private delegate void ClearListViewItemsDelegate(ListView view);

    private void ClearListView(ListView view)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new ClearListViewItemsDelegate(ClearListView), new object[] { view });
            return;
        }

        view.Items.Clear();
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                ClearListView(listView1);

            var item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Name = i.ToString();
            item.Text = item.Name;
            AddItemToListView(listView1, item);
        }
    }
}
```

And for WPF something similar is required. Note this is not working code. As I don't use WPF I can't vouch that this is solid code, but it should give you an idea. You may need to create an type derived from EventArgs to encapsulate your listview and listviewitems.

If I get time, I'll edit this post so that it works, but that will have to wait until this evening!

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
...


if (listView1.Dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
{
    listView1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new EventHandler<ListViewAddEventArgs>(AddItemToListView), sender, new object[] { e } );
    return;
}
listView1.Items.Add(e.File);
```

Comment: Could you provide a comparison between WPF and WinForms aswell?